# How to cast IEnumerable to anonymous type with selected fields

Tags: c#, linq, casting, ienumerable

So, I have some string Array:

**Column1
Column3**

and I have class with fields

```
class A
{
 object Column1;
 object Column2;
 object Column3;
 object Column4;
 object Column5; 
}
```

Now I have a list of A objects

```
List<A> ListOfA = new List<A>();
```

That list has N elements.

Now, How I can cast it to some object from that array? And have `List<NewAnonymous>`

I want to have list of `new { Column1 = '', Column3=''}` but I never know what columns will be in that array.

Is this even possible? If yes, where i can look for it. I have some code ofcourse but it I think it wont help so i just tried to explain what I want to say

Comment: `ListOfA.Select(d => new { Column1 = d.Column1, Column3=d.Column3} )`?

Comment: but what if there will be 3 columns in Array? or 1 ? Or 99999? I never know how much columns with come here with array

Comment: Then don't declare the Columns as properties but rather have a List of a List?

Comment: I have no other choice, I have to base on data that i get

Comment: I would then say use reflection and build a list of a list

Comment: I think missed the point and my explanation was wrong in some way. I have List<A>, with 1000 elements, and based on array i want to create object based on string Array and cast that List<A> to object with fields from that array. I cannot hard code that object

Comment: @Taumantis I can understand you cannot change what you got (the **INPUT** data), but are there any real difficulty to modify what you provide (the **OUTPUT** data)? If not, then think again your design, there could be some better way than passing some dynamically structured data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments on the question I would suggest:

```
foreach (A a in listOfA)
{
    var t = typeof(A);
    List<object> list = new List<object>();

    foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties())
    {
        list.Add(prop.GetValue(a));

    }
    newListOfA.Add(list);
}
```

**Edit:**
If you prefer non query based LINQ here is an extension on EarthEngine's LINQ

```
t = typeof(A)
listOfA.SelectMany(o=>t.GetProperties().Select(i=>i.GetValue(o))
```

Comment: I think missed the point and my explanation was wrong in some way. I have List<A>, with 1000 elements, and based on array i want to create object based on string Array and cast that List<A> to object with fields from that array. I cannot hard code that object

Comment: @Taumantis the example is not hardcoded. It reads the object propeties and adds it to a list containing all the objects where the columns are represented as another list

Comment: so based on array lets say I have "Column6" and now i want to   cast that List<A> list to List<B> where B is dynamically created object that 'is' class B{ Column6 } and have all data that List<A> contains in field Column6. I know it is very bad typoe of request but could you give me more information or edit answer based on my "retarded" exmplanations? Sorry for my english i have big problems with express myslef

Comment: @Taumantis First a question. How do you know if the column does not exist? Does it have a null in the A object or what?

Comment: object of A is always filled with data all fields are filled. For now i just convert List<A> to CSV, then converting CSV to datatable, then removing columns from DT that i dont want, and then converting to CSV again. What i want is to get List<B> becouse i want simply convert List<B> to CSV file. And I dont know how many columns will come with Array but the columns (fields names) will always come. Array can be 3, 4 , 5 ,6 elements and there is not entry if there is null

Answer (score 1):

Same answer as Murdock's, but with pure LINQ

```
from a in listOfA
let t = typeof(A)
from prop in t.GetProperties()
select prop.GetValue(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to buck the current trend and say you could do so via reflection, but you shouldn't.

Why? Because now you have an anonymous type that you don't "know" the properties of. How will you use that downstream? More reflection?

If you have an unknown number of fields it would be best to deal with them in an indexed manner (List or Dictionary) as opposed to that sinkhole of reflection.

Comment: One other option could be `Dynamic` objects?